# Unable to find Lightning Component when creating new version of managed package

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package

I get the error:

```
AuraDefinitionBundle - ComponentName    No COMPONENT named markup://PackageNameSpace:ComponentName found
```

I can't figure out how to resolve this when I create my managed package.  Previously, this component has always uploaded just fine with the managed package.  It only recently started having an issue.  I tried updating the API version of components in my org.  I tried enabling automatic updates.  I tried various things that might have been somewhat similar issues in google searches and nothing has helped.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Even we are facing the same issues. Deployed latest code to the Packaging org and trying to create a Beta. Upload fails with the same lightning component error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes there is some breakage in Salesforce dependencies recalculation.

Try to add some dummy code to your component like `<span></span>` and upload a package again to make Salesforce dependencies to be refreshed next time package is uploaded.

This worked for us.

Comment: I didn't get to experiment with this.... as I came in today and created a package and it magically worked.  This fix MIGHT have worked though as it sounds like that could be why it started magically working.  If it happens again I'll have to test it.

Comment: This did end up working.  I don't know if it was coincidence or if it actually worked but I actually removed a span I had around the component that I didn't think I needed and it worked.